# Calling java from Octave

Tags: java, octave

I am working on some script which uses the xpath classes. There is no implementation in Octave of the equivalent **import** function in Matlab. I found here http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/java-class-access-pitfalls that Matlab cannot create object with non-public constructor. I assume it is similar in Octave. So line

```
javaObject("javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory")
error: [java] java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory
```

gives error. However, there is a public static class method that returns the class reference **newInstance**, so it is possible to create a class.
The **XPathConstans** class has no similar method. Is there any way to make that class accessible in Octave?

```
javaaddpath("C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/rt.jar");

% Construct the DOM.
% These 3 lines are equivalent to xDoc = xmlread(filename) in matlab
parser = javaObject("com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser");
parser.parse(filename); 
xDoc = parser.getDocument;

% Create an XPath expression.
%factory = javaObject("javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory");
factory = javaMethod("newInstance","javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory")
xpath = factory.newXPath
expression = xpath.compile('//demosection/label');

% Apply the expression to the DOM.
%constants = javaObject("javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants")
nodeList = expression.evaluate(xDoc,XPathConstants.NODESET);

% Iterate through the nodes that are returned.
for i = 1:nodeList.getLength
    node = nodeList.item(i-1);
    disp(char(node.getFirstChild.getNodeValue))
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a static field of the `XPathConstants` class. For accessing fields, you use `java_get()`. Since the class has no construct, you need to use it with the class name (instead of an instance of the class):

```
octave> java_get ("javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants", "NODESET")
ans =

<Java object: javax.xml.namespace.QName>

octave> java_get ("javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants", "NODESET").toString ()
ans = {http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}NODESET
```